# How to specify an argument when it also needs to be a string

Tags: r, function

I have written a small function to write out a data frame to Stata .dta format.

```
dta <- function(data.in = dat){
  haven::write_dta(data.in, here("Analysis", "data", "datasets", "stata_dat.dta"), version = 14)
}
```

What I would like to do though is to have a `data.out` argument so that I can specify a name rather than stata_dat.dta, in the event I want to write out multiple dataframes. How do I do this when the data.out argument also needs to be a string in the object save path?

Comment: Would this not work? `dta <- function(data.in = dat, data.out="stata_data.dta"){ haven::write_dta(data.in, here("Analysis", "data", "datasets", data.out), version = 14) }`. A string is just like any other value.

Comment: Yes it would - thank you so much. Can I accept your comment as an answer (not sure how these things work)

Answer (score 0):

@MrFlick the comment is great.

An alternative would be using

> deparse(substitute())

```
dta <- function(data.in = dat, data.out=out.dta){
    outname=deparse(substitute(data.out))
          haven::write_dta(data.in, here("Analysis", "data", "datasets", outname), version = 14)
        }
```

Comment: I would strong recommend against this. It doest appear that `out.dta` is an actual object so passing it as a symbol doesn't make a lot of sense. Plus it makes the function much harder to use programmatically in loops and such. If you do want to use `substitute(deparse())`, it's better to set that as a default parameter value that you can still aways override. For example `dta <- function(data.in = dat, data.out=deparse(substitute(data.in))){haven::write_dta(data.in, here("Analysis", "data", "datasets", data.out), version = 14)}`